# Solve the homogeneous differential equation $(4y+3x)dy+(y-2x)dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Let $\dfrac yx = v$. Then, $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = v+x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(4y+3x) \ \mathrm dy + (y-2x) \ \mathrm dx &=& 0 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& \dfrac{2-\frac yx}{3+4\frac yx} \\
v+x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} &=& \dfrac{2-v}{3+4v} \\
x\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx} &=& \dfrac{2-4v-4v^2}{3+4v} \\
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{(4v+3)\ \mathrm dv}{-4v^2-4v+2} &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x} \\
\end{array}$$

I am not able to solve this integral. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To find $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{(4v+3)\ \mathrm dv}{-4v^2-4v+2}$:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
4v+3 &=& A(-8v-4) + B \\
A &=& -\dfrac{1}{2} \\
B &=& 1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\displaystyle \int \dfrac{(4v+3)\ \mathrm dv}{-4v^2-4v+2} \\
=& \displaystyle -\dfrac12 \int \dfrac{(-8v-4)\ \mathrm dv}{-4v^2-4v+2} + \int \dfrac{\mathrm dv}{-4v^2-4v+2} \\
=& \displaystyle -\dfrac12 \int \dfrac{\mathrm d(-4v^2-4v+2)}{-4v^2-4v+2} + \int \dfrac{\mathrm dv}{-4(v+0.5)^2+3} \\
=& \displaystyle -\dfrac12 \ln\left|(-4v^2-4v+2)\right| - \dfrac14 \int \dfrac{\mathrm dv}{(v+0.5)^2-0.75} \\
=& \displaystyle -\dfrac12 \ln\left|(-4v^2-4v+2)\right| - \dfrac1{4\sqrt3} \int \left(\dfrac{1}{v+0.5-\sqrt{0.75}} - \dfrac{1}{v+0.5+\sqrt{0.75}}\right) \ \mathrm dv \\
=& \displaystyle -\dfrac12 \ln\left|(-4v^2-4v+2)\right| - \dfrac1{4\sqrt3} \left(\ln \left|(v+0.5-\sqrt{0.75})\right| - \ln \left|(v+0.5+\sqrt{0.75})\right|\right) + C\\
\end{array}$$